# Automa installing error in print - Python

Tags: python, automation, python-import, cpython

I need to use [automa package](https://www.getautoma.com/) in python to automate the process in the windows custom application which is created by me.

But, when i use `pip install automa` it shows error in print statement has no parentheses. [image]

What to do... Any suggestion would be help full for me

Comment: in python3 instead of `print "yolo"` you need to use parentheses: `print("yolo")`

Comment: it's a python 2 package that you're trying to install on python 3

Comment: thank you, Is there any way to use automa in python 3...